# How does shuffling influence ANN training?

Tags: neural-networks, training-error

I am wondering how shuffling will influence ANN training.

I assume, we a batch training using the entire data for training at each epoch. Shuffling does not change the value of the error

$$
E={\frac {1}{2n}}\sum _{x}\lVert (y(x)-y'(x))\rVert ^{2}
$$

Hence it does not  make sense to me that it influences the training result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that if batch were used, shuffling would not change the value of the error.  Generally batch is *not* used.  Usually mini-batch is used, so the weights are updated after seeing a subset of the training set.  In this case, shuffling does change the training result.

Batch is not used because it is inefficient, requiring a sweep through the entire dataset for each update.

Comment: I use batch because my training is offline and the time does not matter to me at all.